# Append text in the end of line if search pattern is found

Tags: regex, perl

This is my first question on this forum :).

I have a file something like:

```
----File--------
XI39/XM79 XI39/XM79#G XI39/XM79#S XI39/XM79#D XI39/XM79#B XI39/XM79#DN append_text! 
+ search_pattern
+ w=5e-07 l=3.85e-07 sa=4.1e-07 sb=4.1e-07 ad=2.05e-13 as=2.05e-13 pd=1.82e-06

XI57/XM0@1 XI57/XM0@1#G XI57/XM0@1#S XI57/XM0@1#D XI57/XM0@1#B XI57/XM0@1#DN
+ search_pattern
+ w=1e-06 l=3.85e-07 sa=4.1e-07 sb=1.215e-06 ad=2.1e-13 as=4.1e-13 pd=1.42e-06
```

---

I want to search for "search_pattern" and if found look at one line above and append "append_text!" in end of line if its not present.

So the output file should be:-

------------output file------

```
XI39/XM79 XI39/XM79#G XI39/XM79#S XI39/XM79#D XI39/XM79#B XI39/XM79#DN append_text! 
+ search_pattern
+ w=5e-07 l=3.85e-07 sa=4.1e-07 sb=4.1e-07 ad=2.05e-13 as=2.05e-13 pd=1.82e-06

XI57/XM0@1 XI57/XM0@1#G XI57/XM0@1#S XI57/XM0@1#D XI57/XM0@1#B XI57/XM0@1#DN append_text!
+ search_pattern
+ w=1e-06 l=3.85e-07 sa=4.1e-07 sb=1.215e-06 ad=2.1e-13 as=4.1e-13 pd=1.42e-06
```

---

I know perl a little so can do file operations but not good at all with pattern matching. Any pointer will be helpful.

Comment: Hi @sandeepsingh. Welcome to SO. Please do mention your tries too. Please read [how to ask a good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I will keep it in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a line buffer. You read lines from the file and save the previous one you've read. When you find a line that matches your criteria, you modify the previous line and output it. The current line becomes the previous line and you keep going:

```
use v5.12;
use warnings;

chomp( my $previous_line = <> );
while( <> ) {
    chomp;
    if( /search_pattern/ and $previous_line !~ / append_text!\z/ ) {
        $previous_line .= " append_text!";
        }

    say $previous_line;
    $previous_line = $_;
    }

say $previous_line;
```

This is something that someone on the second day of my [Learning Perl](https://www.learningperl.com) could do and understand. There are no fancy regex features.

The same thing works if the previous interesting line is further away. You can keep a small line window array and once you find the line that triggers an action, do whatever you want to the previous lines:

```
use v5.12;
use warnings;

my $buffer_size = 3;
my @line_window = map { scalar <> } 1 .. $buffer_size;
chomp( @line_window );

while( <> ) {
    chomp;
    if( /search_pattern/ and $line_window[0] !~ / append_text!\z/ ) {
        $line_window[0] .= " append_text!";
        }

    say shift @line_window;
    push @line_window, $_;
    }

say join "\n", @line_window;
```

Answer (score 1):

We can append the text in more ways.. Lets try this one

Push all your data into array

```
push(@allline, <DATA>);
```

Iterate for loop

```
for(my $i=0; $i < $#allline; $i++)
{
```

Catch up the `Matched line` and `previous line`

```
    my $j = $i; $j--;
```

If matches found then go back to the previous line

```
    if($allline[$i]=~m/\+\s*search_pattern/)
    {
```

Check the `append_text` availability

```
        if($allline[$j]!~m/append_text/)
        {
            $allline[$j]=~s/$/ \*\*append_text\*\*/;
        }
        elsif($allline[$j]=~m/append_text/)
        {
            $allline[$j]=~s/append_text/\*\*append_text\*\*/;
        }
    }
}
```

Check your output

```
print join "", @allline;


__DATA__
XI39/XM79 XI39/XM79#G XI39/XM79#S XI39/XM79#D XI39/XM79#B XI39/XM79#DN append_text! 
+ search_pattern
+ w=5e-07 l=3.85e-07 sa=4.1e-07 sb=4.1e-07 ad=2.05e-13 as=2.05e-13 pd=1.82e-06

XI57/XM0@1 XI57/XM0@1#G XI57/XM0@1#S XI57/XM0@1#D XI57/XM0@1#B XI57/XM0@1#DN
+ search_pattern
+ w=1e-06 l=3.85e-07 sa=4.1e-07 sb=1.215e-06 ad=2.1e-13 as=4.1e-13 pd=1.42e-06
```

Output

```
 XI39/XM79 XI39/XM79#G XI39/XM79#S XI39/XM79#D XI39/XM79#B XI39/XM79#DN \*\*append_text\*\*!
 + search_pattern
 + w=5e-07 l=3.85e-07 sa=4.1e-07 sb=4.1e-07 ad=2.05e-13 as=2.05e-13 pd=1.82e-06

 XI57/XM0@1 XI57/XM0@1#G XI57/XM0@1#S XI57/XM0@1#D XI57/XM0@1#B XI57/XM0@1#DN \*\*append_text\*\*
 + search_pattern
 + w=1e-06 l=3.85e-07 sa=4.1e-07 sb=1.215e-06 ad=2.1e-13 as=4.1e-13 pd=1.42e-06
```

Comment: You're cycling through an array, but you don't really care about all the lines before the previous one, and you don't yet care about the ones coming up. Instead, you can read a window of lines at a time and only deal with those.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Everyone for sharing there thought. it was really insightful and encourage me more to learn.

### Based on various reply this is something I wrote and went with:-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(FH, "</home/sksingh/file");
my $this_line = "";
my $line_to_print = "";
while(<FH>) {
    my $last_line = $this_line;
    $this_line = $_;
    $line_to_print = $last_line;
    if ($this_line =~ /search_pattern/) {
        if($last_line =~ /append_txt!/) {
          $line_to_print = $last_line;
        }
        else {
          chomp($last_line);
          $line_to_print = "$last_line" . "psub!\n";
        }
      }
    print $line_to_print;
}
close (FH);
```

---

Again thanks for reply.

Currently the input file is of around 100 mb. It in coming days i might have to precess file up till 3 GB. Not sure how this code will scale but for now I am good to go.

---Sandeep---

Answer (score 0):

Desired result can be achieved with perl one liner

`perl -007 -pe "s/(#DN)(\s+\+ search_pattern)/$1 append_text!$2/gs" filename`

Or you could use following perl code (NOTE: it uses DATA block for test purpose)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

$data =~ s/(#DN)(\s+\+ search_pattern)/$1 append_text!$2/gs;

say $data;

__DATA__
----File--------
XI39/XM79 XI39/XM79#G XI39/XM79#S XI39/XM79#D XI39/XM79#B XI39/XM79#DN append_text! 
+ search_pattern
+ w=5e-07 l=3.85e-07 sa=4.1e-07 sb=4.1e-07 ad=2.05e-13 as=2.05e-13 pd=1.82e-06

XI57/XM0@1 XI57/XM0@1#G XI57/XM0@1#S XI57/XM0@1#D XI57/XM0@1#B XI57/XM0@1#DN
 + search_pattern
 + w=1e-06 l=3.85e-07 sa=4.1e-07 sb=1.215e-06 ad=2.1e-13 as=4.1e-13 pd=1.42e-06
```

Or even better with *look behind* to not includes `append_text!` in regular expression (for case if the line before `+ search_pattern` has irregular pattern)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

$data =~ s/(?<!append_text!)(\s+\+ search_pattern)/ append_text!$1/gs;

say $data;

__DATA__
----File--------
XI39/XM79 XI39/XM79#G XI39/XM79#S XI39/XM79#D XI39/XM79#B XI39/XM79#DN append_text! 
+ search_pattern
+ w=5e-07 l=3.85e-07 sa=4.1e-07 sb=4.1e-07 ad=2.05e-13 as=2.05e-13 pd=1.82e-06

XI57/XM0@1 XI57/XM0@1#G XI57/XM0@1#S XI57/XM0@1#D XI57/XM0@1#B XI57/XM0@1#DN
+ search_pattern
+ w=1e-06 l=3.85e-07 sa=4.1e-07 sb=1.215e-06 ad=2.1e-13 as=4.1e-13 pd=1.42e-06
```

Output

```
----File--------
XI39/XM79 XI39/XM79#G XI39/XM79#S XI39/XM79#D XI39/XM79#B XI39/XM79#DN append_text!
+ search_pattern
+ w=5e-07 l=3.85e-07 sa=4.1e-07 sb=4.1e-07 ad=2.05e-13 as=2.05e-13 pd=1.82e-06

XI57/XM0@1 XI57/XM0@1#G XI57/XM0@1#S XI57/XM0@1#D XI57/XM0@1#B XI57/XM0@1#DN append_text!
 + search_pattern
 + w=1e-06 l=3.85e-07 sa=4.1e-07 sb=1.215e-06 ad=2.1e-13 as=4.1e-13 pd=1.42e-06
```

Comment: You don't need to read in an entire file, but that's one of your favorite tactics. It's really bad advice.

Comment: @briandfoy -- it is bad only if file big enough, if file a few megabytes I do not see where the problem could be. This way code looks quite compact and take just a few lines of code. If OP was specific that the file is huge in size then other approach would be taken.

Comment: When there's a way that's never a problem no matter the file size, don't use a way that's a problem with some file sizes. You need to get used to more robust programming, and it's a bad thing to show off to people.

Comment: @briandfoy -- put your answer and we will see what you 'have up in your sleeve'.

Comment: There's nothing up my sleeve, so have your answer. It's something you really need to learn and I'll continue to downvote answers where you read in an entire file before doing anything with the data. This way you don't create bugs like using `\s` to match line endings. Your regex is too complicated for the job and too imprecise for the input, which is how those bugs sneak in.

Comment: @briandfoy -- are you sure that there will not be space at the end of the line? What gives you this assurance?

Comment: I didn't say there wouldn't be a space at the end of a line. If things need to be on separate lines, however, there needs to be a line separator in there. Your regex doesn't require such a thing.

Comment: @briandfoy -- and what that separator would be? Dos, UNIX, classic Mac or something else?

Comment: `\R` is the generic line ending, and `\v` is any vertical whitespace. You can read about these in [Learning Perl](https://www.learningperl.com).

Answer (score -1):

```
while(<Your filehandle name>)
{
if ($string =~ m/search_pattern/g) 
{
$_=~ s/append_text/**append_text**/g;
}
close(filehandle name)
```

Comment: You need to change the previous line.